# How to query the maximum value of two columns in two different tables?

Tags: sql

I have a requirement.

I have two tables say TableA and TableB. Both having a column called "rec_id". My requirement is to get the maximum of the values contained in these two columns using a single query.

eg: In TableA, I have "rec_id" values as {1,5,6} and in TableB, I have "rec_id" values as {1,4,2}. So after executing the query, I want "6" as the result since 6 is the maximum value from these two columns, out of these two tables.

Thanks in Advance,
Anish Kurian

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
select max(rec_id) from 
(
  (select rec_id from tablea)
 union all
  (select rec_id from tableb)
) combined
```

Comment: @Bill Karwin sometimes its about the luck over skill. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

```
select max(rec_id) from 
(
  (select MAX(rec_id) AS rec_id from tablea)
 union
  (select MAX(rec_id) AS rec_id from tableb)
) combined
```

In comparison to Nathan Feger's answer this would be more performant

Comment: "In comparison to Nathan Feger's answer this would be more performant" - not necessarily; it depends on how the DB engine handles it. I would actually expect it to perform slightly worse, as you still have to scan through all rec_id values in both tables, but your query has to derive three maximum values whereas Nathan's only has to derive one.

Comment: With index covered `rec_id` there will be no scans. The max values are taken with O(1) complexity.

Comment: Nope. Since indexes in mysql is B-Tree, which is sorted structure, mysql optimizer can take the max value using only one read operation. So, for 2 indexes it will be 2 read operations and very fast comparison of 2 ints. And in checked answer it will be fullscan. Create 2 tables with 10M records each and check it.